# Postgres Counts based on Month and Years

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a psql table

```
Points
id (SERIAL) | user(INTEGER) | time_of_point(TIMESTAMP) | title (TEXT)
```

I want to get a break down of users points that shows their points the current month, current year, and the lifetime.

I'm a bit lost on how to do this. What would the query look like?

The final table should look like this

```
User | Points (this month) | Points (this year) | Lifetime Points
1    |     5               |     10             |     216
2    |     7               |     14             |     125
3    |    15               |    140             |     325
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about conditional aggregation?

```
select user,
       sum(points) filter (where date_trunc('month', time_of_point) = date_trunc('month', now()) as this_month,
       sum(points) filter (where date_trunc('year', time_of_point) = date_trunc('year', now()) as this_year,
       sum(points) as lifetime
from t
group by user;
```

Comment: This seems to be working! One last question. If i want to show the firstName and lastName of the user (from the user's table), I am trying to do a join, but i am getting the error " must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: Along with this, I would like to show users where their sum/count is 0

Comment: @Phil . . . This is showing all users from the one table you have mentioned in the query.  There is no filtering.  If you want additional information from `users` -- and all the rows in that table -- then use `LEFT JOIN`.